# Minimizing $\int_0^1 [f''(x)]^2 dx$ with constraints

Tags: integration, integral-inequality

I would like to find the greatest lower bound and hopefully the function that minimizes $\int_0^1 [f’’(x)]^2 dx$ where $f\in C^2([0,1])$ with $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ and $f’(0) = 1$.

The only thing I could think of to bound the integral was Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$\left(\int_0^1 f’’(x)dx\right)^2 \leq \int_0^1 (1)^2dx\int_0^1 [f’’(x)]^2dx \\ \implies \int_0^1[f’’(x)]^2dx \geq [f’(1) – f’(0)]^2 = [f’(1) – 1]^2$$

But this involves $f’(1)$ which is not known.

Comment: Perhaps extending $f$ to a periodic function with period $1$ and using Fourier series might provide an answer.

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of the following questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219139/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257404/ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264629/